# Western Digital my passport 2TB

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-failure

My passport WD 2TB is about 2 years old and was working perfectly on both PC and Mac up to yesterday.

Today when I plugged it in, it whirred loudly.

The power light is continuously flashing.

It is not showing up on the Finder or any other place on my Mac.

I really need the data.

I have read it might be a power or over heating issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Its neither.  Its a mechanical issue which is out of your hands to fix.

Comment: The drive is toast. As Ramhound said, mechanical failure.
Recover the data from a backup which you hopefully made. If there are no backups then no longer use the drive. Do not even try to power it on. Instead take it to a professional recovery service. Downside: No guarantees of recovered data and it is expensive.

Comment: In future you should look into a NAS - (quality ones like Synology) supports RAID, which saves you from mechanical failure

Comment: @gudthing You might want to mention *not* using RAID 0 if resiliency is required.

Comment: @AndrewMorton very good point, can't edit my point above but definitely read up on RAID (if it interests you OP)

Comment: Will definitely read up on RAID. I'm not thrilled to hear it's probably a mechanical issue as unfortunately some of the more recently added files are not backed up. To my knowledge it is still under warranty - so I'll be contacting WD first thing tomorrow morning. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a mechanical fault.

If you **REALLY** need that data, you have 2 choices:

1. Send it to an expensive data recovery service
2. Attempt to recover what you can using a dedicated tool.

There are a number of tools that will attempt to recover the data from the drive as best they can. The one I've found most consistent at actually recovering useful data is [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com). However, this is not free, at around USD90 is it relatively expensive. Of course, this is far less than a data recovery service is likely to cost.

The other thing to note is that data recovery can be a long, slow process. I've had Spinrite running for over a week on a badly damaged drive (it did recover a fair bit in that instance, enough to reboot the PC temporarily) - other people have had it running for over a month! It does sometimes appear to work miracles but it the disks spindle has failed or some other serious hardware fault developed, only a data recovery service will get anything at all.

---

Regarding people's comments on RAID. This is of limited or no use if you want to use external, portable drives. Of course, portable drives are also MUCH more prone to hardware faults due to being moved about more than average.

The real answer to preventing this from occurring in the future is to have a good **backup** process in place.

Backups need to be automated & foolproof. Backups should also always go "somewhere else". Ideally 1 backup locally for rapid recovery and 1 backup remotely for additional security. I recommend [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com) for both of these if you only want a single tool.